# Solution curves for $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$

Tags: calculus

Find the general solution of the differential equation and sketch the family of solution curves represented by the general solution.

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y$$

The answer given in the book is:

$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int dx$; therefore

$ln \ y = x + C$; so

$y = e^{x+C}$. Thus,

$y = e^xe^C$; hence

$y = Ae^x$, where $A = e^C$.

But when the solution curves are drawn, some of them have a negative $A$ giving negative values of $y$. How can this be?  $A$ must be positive.

Comment: Solutions of differential equations never assume the functions and variables to be real, so there is no restriction to the sign of the integration constant, $C$ or $A$. If you wrote $\ln y - \ln A = x$ at the beginning, you could do $\ln \frac{y}{A}=x$ and now you see that even a difference of two logarithms of negative numbers yields a positive result when you get a quotient.

Answer (score 3):

Actually $\displaystyle\int\frac{dy}y=\ln|y|$

So, we have $\displaystyle|y|=e^{x+c}$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant

For real $\displaystyle x, \frac{|y|}{e^c}=e^x>0$

So, $|y|,e^c$ must have same sign

Answer (score 0):

First of all $y' = y$ is a very good equation, so we could expect that there is only one integral curve goes throw each point. It is easy to see that $A e^x$ is a solution. Also it could be checked easily that $A e^x$ goes throw all points for corresponding $A$. That implies there are only one class of solutions $A e^x$. So on that way there is nothing to state that A should be positive. (Try, for your understanding, $0 (A=0), e^x (A = 1), e^{-x}(A = -1)$.